# I'm trying to use bower to write static Web-apps, how should I unify all css and javascript?

Tags: bower

I'm writing static webpages, using html, css and javascript.

I use angular and write lot's of components. I'm testing bower to keep track of them. It works fine, however, I would like to compress all javascript and css in one file. I would also like to have a non–minified version of the files.

Comment: comment on the downvote would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Grunt (or Gulp if that appeals more to you) to bundle & minify your scripts & CSS, http://love2dev.com/#!article/Using-GruntJS-to-Bundle-and-Minify-JavaScript-and-CSS

I am ASP.NET developer so it is pretty easy to load either the individual files for development or the minified versions in production. This is what it looks like in my applications:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
   {CSS or JS Links to individual files go here}
}else{
   {minified CSS or JS goes here}
}
```

}

In the web.config you just flip the debug flag to false for production:

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```